# TYPE_INT_ARGB images are not shown correctly

Tags: java, image

I am creating an image with random pixels and an integer in the middle. However, the color just doesn't seem right.

[image: click!]

As you can see, the color is not right. Here's the code

```
private void createImage(){
    try{
        String key = "3534";
        BufferedImage thumbnail = new BufferedImage(300, 300,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics graphics = thumbnail.getGraphics();
        graphics.setFont(new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 100));

        randomizePixels(graphics);

        graphics.setColor(new Color(255,255,255,255));
        graphics.drawString(key, thumbnail.getWidth()/2, thumbnail.getHeight()/2);

        ImageIO.write(thumbnail,"jpg",new File("c:\\image1.jpg"));
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void randomizePixels(Graphics graphics){
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int k=0;k<300;k++){
        for(int j=0;j<300;j++){
            graphics.setColor(new Color(random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat()));
            graphics.fillRect(k,j,1,1);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've set the color of number (255,255,255,255), which is white with 100% opacity.

Is there anything that I must be doing wrong? How can I get my number to be white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'm getting slightly different result when running your code. The dots should have random color, not all red as you are posting.

[image]

I'm not sure what exactly you want to accomplish, but I guess you want a random noise and put an overlay with partially visible text. I'd start with using png as an output format. I'm not sure how the jpg handles transparency. 
So you should first paint the randomized pixels with solid color and then write over that the text. 
You need to move setting the color after you randomize the pixels like this:

```
private static void createImage(){
    try{
        String key = "3534";
        BufferedImage thumbnail = new BufferedImage(300, 300,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics graphics = thumbnail.getGraphics();

        randomizePixels(graphics);

        graphics.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255 ,255));
        graphics.setFont(new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 100));
        graphics.drawString(key, thumbnail.getWidth()/2, thumbnail.getHeight()/2);
        ImageIO.write(thumbnail, "png", new File("image1.png"));
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private static void randomizePixels(Graphics graphics){
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int k=0;k<300;k++){
        for(int j=0;j<300;j++){
            graphics.setColor(new Color(random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat(), random.nextFloat(),1));
            graphics.fillRect(k,j,1,1);
        }
    }
}
```

After that, the text will get the color you want / with "hidden" text

[image] [image]

Comment: I am trying to load test my web server(it only accepts 64x64 jpg). I've figured that most random noise results in big size. Also, the numbers in the image is to check whether images are uploaded correctly. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Of course random noise results in big size. In theory, it has maximal possible entropy so it's hard to compress:)
Anyway if you're concerned about the results, you should always start with solid filled picture(and you can apply alpha channel to other operations), because transparency can be displayed different on different browsers.